# A complicated math issue

Tags: math

> *[ *ms = milliseconds ]*

Imagine that you have a timeline starting at `162000 ms (00:02:42.000)`, and ending at `10358500 ms (02:52:28.500)`. You have a marker placed at `4974123 ms (01:22:44.123)`.

Now, this timeline can be dragged in any way - as long as the start time is smaller that the end time. For example, this is valid: `580000 ms to 610000 ms`. This is not: `610000 ms to 580000 ms`.

So, imagine that we drag this timeline to start at `338100 ms (03:00:32.100)`, and ending at `10842200 ms (03:00:32.200)`. So: What time is the marker placed on now? And how do I calculate this?

Comment: `338100 ms (03:00:32.100)` this does not make sense. Moreover I do not understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? A drawing would be nice. You have three markers placed in sequence and you can move only the most left and most right ones and the middle one moves linearly with the other two? Is that how this works?

Comment: The only “complicated” thing about it is that the behavior of the marker is undefied in respect to boundary changes.

Comment: Imagine that you have a rope that is 10 m, and a blue spot at 4 m. If you then drag this rope so that it becomes 12 m instead - where on the rope is that blue spot now?

Comment: This website is more likely to receive questions about programming, perhaps you can get better answers at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Igor Sevo: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @PicrofoSoftware: Although this is a calculation very often used in GUI programming (for instance).

Comment: After the explanations I understand now. I might be wrong, but I think I would call this "stretching" (or "shrinking", rather than "dragging". And Ondrej is still right that the description lacks a definition of how the marker is expected to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong -- this is a very *simple* mathematical issue. If the initial interval is from 100 to 300 and the marker is at 120, it is located (120 - 100)/(300-100) = 10 % of the span from the starting point.

If you change the interval to 500 to 530, the marker should still (I suppose you mean like that) be 10 % of the span from 500 to 530, that is, at 500 + 0.1 * 30 = 503.

Comment: So... for my example it goes like this?:

Comment: So... for my example it goes like this?:

(4974123 - 162000) / (10358500 - 162000) = 0.4719387044574119 %

338100 + 0.004719387044574119 * ? = ?

By the way - where did you get 30 from? Is it 530 - 500?

I'llclarify it...

Comment: (1) You must learn what `%` means: 0.4719... = 47.19... % (2), yes, you go 47 % of the new span, which is `530 - 500 = 30` in my example. So obviously you should do 338100 + 0.4719... * (10842200 - 338100)

Comment: Oh ok. So like this then I suppose:

(marker - start) / (end - start) = the%

newstart + (the% * 0.01) * (newend - newstart) = Answer

Comment: @spunit: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try and implement this now that I know how to calculate it. I'll accept this answer right now anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @spunit: You're welcome. [Just remember what `%` means: If the first calculation gives you 0.3 (= 30 %), you should use `0.3 *` in the second one. So actually there is no place where you should divide by 100.]